# Flask get all pictures links from google drive folders

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api

I need help
I develop a website in python with flask
And i want get all pictures links from my google drive public folder
I found PyDrive but i don't want manage client google drive
have you a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey
thanks for all
I found my problem
The storage of service account is on Firebase and not GoogleDrive
I use pyrebase and it work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use PyDrive to make requests to the Drive API. You can use the REST API directly. Or you could use the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) to make your life easier.

My suggestion is you go through [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) to make authenticated requests to Drive API using Python.

Comment: I can only find ways to create clients.
But I want my script use its storage or use my storage on Google Drive.

Comment: "I can only find ways to create clients." Where? "I want my script use its storage" Show your script and maybe we can help.